# How to split two numerical values into two columns?

Tags: r, split

I have tried my best using the split function and others, but to no avail.

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Why did you remove the example? Without it, the question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `read.table/read.csv` with the `sep` option.

```
read.table(text=as.character(df1$datetime), sep=' ', 
         col.names=c('date', 'time'),
            header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#        date time
#1 01/01/2011 0:00
#2 01/01/2011 1:00
#3 01/01/2011 2:00
#4 01/01/2011 3:00
#5 01/01/2011 4:00
```

---

Or with `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, datetime, into= c('date', 'time'), sep=' ')
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, thank you so much for your help! It worked! :)